# is there any realtion between linearity and the axioms of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any relation between linearity (aditivity and homogeneity)

Additivity: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Homogeneity: $f(αx) = αf(x)$ for all α.

And the [axioms for a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)?

Does one motivate the other? are vector spaces linear because linearity can be constructed from those axioms?

Comment: The definitions are set up to be compatible with each other: vector spaces are the structures for which homomorphisms (structure-preserving maps) are linear maps.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by calling a vector space "linear." Linearity isn't a property of a vector space, it is a property of certain transformations. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A linear function will be an Homomorphism of vector spaces.
Hence you can say the notion of linearity arises from the axioms of a vector space since it conserves them.

Answer (score 0):

> Does one motivate the other?

Linear transformations are essentially homomorphisms between the additive groups of two vector spaces. Homogeneity, in your sense, is only preserved if the transformation is between two vector spaces over the same field. This follows because the distributive laws must be obeyed in both.

> [A]re vector spaces linear because linearity can be constructed from those axioms?

Vector space and linear space are two terms for the same thing. Although I am not entirely sure regarding the etymology of the term, it is suggestive that linear spaces are 'linear' in the sense that every automorphism acts linearly on linear combinations in the space. The same follows for any homomorphism between two linear spaces over the same field.

Comment: It seems i'm lacking some abstract algebra to interpret this. I will have to get back to this answer after some field theory or something.